# Xubuntu 19.04: xfc4-power-manager can not hibernate on XPS 9570

Tags: xubuntu, dell, power-management, hibernate, xps

my laptop can not hibernate (anymore). I do not know what I changed so that is not working but I am pretty sure that this worked in the past.

I am using Xubuntu 19.04 on a Dell XPS 9570 and also the poer-manager tells me that hibernating is not possible:

```
xfce4-power-manager --dump
---------------------------------------------------
       Xfce power manager version 1.6.1
With policykit support
With network manager support
---------------------------------------------------
Can suspend: True
Can hibernate: False
Authorized to suspend: True
Authorized to hibernate: False
Authorized to shutdown: True
Has battery: True
Has brightness panel: True
Has power button: True
Has hibernate button: True
Has sleep button: True
Has LID: True
```

This is my grub config:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080
```

I personally have no idea where to look next. I googled the issue but found nothing describing a similar problem.

I did some more research and found that the following should be setup on the laptop:

- the SWAP should be >= RAM size so that suspend-to-disk can be performed
- hibernating is working with the following packages `pm-utils` and `uswsusp` and calling `sudo pm-hibernate`

Now I "only" have to find out how to call that from an XFCE4 Menu item and without root privileges.